# replace anything other than a-z,A-Z,0-9 or a space with nothing

Tags: jquery

I am making a registration form. When a user is selecting a username I want jquery to replace anything other than `a-z,A-Z,0-9` or a space with nothing.

So on keyup the form field with the id of username will only allow `a-z,A-Z,0-9` or a space and replace anything else with nothing "".

How could I do that?

Comment: What if the user has JavaScript turned off? Do you also have server-side validation to back it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't just replace those characters, as then the user who signed up with `me!` will wonder why they can't use that to login. If they have characters they type that also disappear, they will be confused. You will always need to bind other events such as `paste`.

Instead, you should validate it with the regular expression `replace(/[^a-zA-Z\d ]/g, '')` and then return to the user if it is valid or not.

Comment: Thats the thing, I want it to show the changes in the field as they are typing.

Comment: @Andrew You don't believe that would be confusing? For example, if you were typing a comment on Stack Overflow and characters were not appearing, would you be confused? Do you know of any other high profile sets that use this method?

Comment: The way I've seen this usually is paired with a warning that "You can't use that character". Windows File Explorer uses it if you type the wrong character in while naming a file, for example.

Comment: @Jared If you wanted to go down that road, ensure you have something similar to the warning in Windows, e.g. a bubble pointed to the input field stating the constraints for that input.

Comment: But, it should be paired with a server-side validation and error message if the JS doesn't work or is disabled.

Comment: @Alex, that's exactly what I'm suggesting (an error message).

Answer (score 0):

```
function myCallback(username) {
   username = username.replace(/[^a-z0-9 ]/gi, '');
   /* do stuff with username now */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').split(' ').join('');
```

Find space to join

```
.split(' ').join('');
```